# Ubuntu 18.04 sudo apt update doesn't work (Failed to Fetch)

Tags: networking, apt, updates, 18.04

I have tried quite many solution to this like prioritizing IPv4 and disabling IPv6 or adding Google DNS server, fix the sources list and some other suggestion on AskUbuntu but nothing worked.

I have also tried with different wifi networks (I can get no access to LAN unfortunately since I am living in a dorm and work in a common workspace with organization internet).

Another thing is that I cannot `ping` also.

I am quite new to Ubuntu so if anyone can help me I would be really grateful. When I enter `sudo apt update` the output is this :

```
Err:1 http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb InRelease        
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.getdeb.net'
Err:2 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease             
  Temporary failure resolving 'packages.ros.org'
Reading package lists... Done      
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/xenial-getdeb/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.getdeb.net'
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'packages.ros.org'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: What are you running?   Your error messages mention two different release of Ubuntu (16.04 LTS & 18.04 LTS), and http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu is not a Ubuntu source, and neither are standard.

Comment: I am running 18.04 LTS right now.

Comment: I would suggest removing those two sources; they are not standard Ubuntu sources; .... Add a "#" to the start of those two entries lines in your sources will comment them out, or you could just remove them.

Comment: As @guiverc says, those sources may be faulty, and it would likely be in your best interest to get rid of them, as a real solution to the problem would be involve installing keyrings to gain access to those sources (had to do so before in antiX linux), which may not be available depending on the repo's level of official-ness or professional-ness.

Comment: Ok I have succesfully removed archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu, and I tried the solution from the possible duplicate but it didn't apply at all. The other post was so long ago so maybe it's quite different.

Comment: What about packages.ros.org? It seems to suffer from the same problem according to your terminal output. Could you update the output if anything changed?

Comment: It's working now!! Thank you so much I did think it was the problem at all.